# Does symbology work on grid layers?

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, vector-grid

I'm using QGIS and I created a grid and joined a column with observation points to it.  I'm trying to use symbology to shade the cells of the grid based on the values that I joined.  But it looks like it just punched a hole in the grid at each of cells instead of coloring them.  Does symbology not work normally with grids?  [image]

[image]

Comment: Which field are you trying to use for graduated color symbology?

Comment: The field is NUM

Comment: Is there any value in that column other than the value `0`?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of different values, it just lists zeros first.

Comment: Can you share your grid file?

Answer (score 1):

Grid works perfect with symbology - just set it to `graduated`, set your field name as `value`, select (or modify of create) a color ramp, select `mode` and number of `classes` (if applicable) and don't forget to press `classify`. So check where you're settings differ from those of mine here - a created an attribute `NUM` with random values from 1 to 1000.

Empty cells could be filled with a color set to transparency - check if your color ramp does not include transparent values. If nothing of this helps, please provide more information about your settings and check if only your grid-layer is visible.

[image]